# how to catch action where user clicks out of uisearchbar to cancel in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uisearchbar

I know that I can capture the cancel action from the user like this:

```
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

However, a user can also click outside of the searchbar on the tableview and it also sends a cancel action, but not to the above cancel action.

How can I get the click outside of the search bar cancel action?

Comment: Are you using a `UISearchDisplayController`? Use its delegate methods for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller;
```

Is what you are looking for.